# Why do I have no intellisense in my app.config?

Tags: configuration, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I want to add an `appSettings` section to my `app.config`, but I am not getting any intellisense. The IDE also has the `configuration` node underlined and says `The configuration element is not declared` when I mouse over it, so I wonder if these two issue are related. It does this when I create a new `app.config` and even when I create an entirely new project. I only have this issue in VS 2019. VS 2010 has intellisense, so something tells me it's a VS setting that points to a reference file containing all the elements available to intellisense.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I have no intellisense in my app.config?

I think your project is created by the old VS2010 version and then migrate into the new VS2019 and the old project type is quite different from VS2019. So there are some factors in your old project which impact intellisense.

You can try these steps:

**1)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`, `obj` folder, then restart your project to test again.

**2)** open menu `XML`-->`Schemas`-->find the entry for `DotNetConfig.xsd`,select `Use this schema` and then click `OK`.

[image]

**3)** If this does not work, please try to add a new `app.config` file to replace the old file and then migrate its content into the new file.

Comment: #2 in your solution worked. I had to select *Use this schema* for *DotNetConfig.xsd*. Intellisense now works properly.